# What is key_0, why am I seeing it in my merged dataframe, and is there a way to prevent it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Python 3.6.5 and Pandas 0.23.0 according to my juptyer notebook query.

I'm merging two dataframes:

```
df_merged1=pd.merge(df_RL, df_BR, how='left',left_on=df_RL['Business Service Manual'], right_on=df_BR['Names'])
```

The left dataframe df_RL.dtypes

```
Server                     object
Server Farm                object
Business Service Manual    object
dtype: object
```

The right dataframe df_BR.dtypes

```
Names    object
dtype: object
```

The resulting merged dataframe df_merged1.dtypes

```
key_0                      object
Server                     object
Server Farm                object
Business Service Manual    object
Names                      object
dtype: object
```

This syntax does what I want it to do for the most part. It's merging my left and right dataframe on 'Business Service Manual' from the left dataframe and 'Names' from the right dataframe.

My issue:
The resulting merged dataframe adds a column called "key_0" that appears to be the exact same as Business Service Manual.
What is it? Why is it? Is there a way for me to prevent it from being added in the merge syntax?

Comment: You should include in your question at least your inputs columns lists and the merged columns list.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Upated

Comment: Do you get the same key_0 column with: `df_merged1=pd.merge(df_RL, df_BR, how='left', left_on='Business Service Manual', right_on='Names')`

Comment: I did not. Can you put that in an answer and I can mark it solved?

Answer (score 1):

I just produced the same output with key_0 and key_1 in case of multiple joins (more than one key in the join). It is because of the join parameters you are passing in is series instead of labels.

```
df_merged1=pd.merge(df_RL, df_BR,how='left',left_on=['BusinessService Manual'], right_on=['Names'])
```

Answer (score -3):

The solution of your problem may be the parameter 'how' of the merge method.
If you want only the columns on your left dataframe just try this version of your merge:

```
df_merged1=pd.merge(df_RL, df_BR, how='left',left_on=df_RL['Business Service Manual'], right_on=df_BR['Names'], how='left')
```

To understand the merge parameters, just give a look to the 
[merge documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

Cheers.

Comment: Hi Felipe, thanks for your answer. However, the only difference between your code and mine is that you duplicated {how='left'}